# Как в PUG указать несколько атрибутов для тега?

Tags: html, css, pug, jade

Мне нужно подключить файл css через pug. Для этого для link нужно указать несколько атрибутов в файле PUG. Я не знаю как это сделать.
Как в PUG указать несколько атрибутов для тега?

Код в PUG:

```
block vars

doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/style.css")
    title= pageTitle
  body
    block content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В "Pug"е атрибуты указываются внутри скобки (сколько хотите туда можно поставить), классы c точкой(.) айдишки с решеткой (#)

Пример:

index.pug

```
a.youtube#last_link(href="http://youtube.com", visible, data-go-to-youtube="false")  Visit YouTube
```

index.html

```
<a 
class="youtube" 
id="last_link" 
href="http://youtube.com" 
visible 
data-go-to-youtube="false">
    Visit YouTube
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ответ, это делается вот так:

link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/style.css')